# Spring RequestMapping Regular Expression: Forward all url's without a dot [.] to index.html

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, controller

This controller maps everything that doesn't have a dot in it to index.html. That is until I add a `/`. Then sadly it no longer matches. How do I edit the RequestMapping or regex to allow multiple '/' in the url?

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect(@PathVariable("path") String path) {     
        return "forward:/";
    }
```

However as soon as a add another forward-slash (subdir) it doesn't match.

`/image.jpg` doesn't match (good)

`/about` does match (good)

`/about/me` doesn't match (bad)

Answer (score 0):

In `@RequestMapping("/**")` to write multiple "/" in your URL

This solves your problem of giving multiple forwardslashes to a **URL**

- /hello/world/
- /welcome/wel/com/me

Every test case will be passed

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. Posting here for the benefit of anyone else that struggles.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/**/{regex:[-a-zA-Z0-9]*}")
public String forward404() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

The Regex above allows any url, but the last section (the bit after the last /) can only be `-`, `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`. This means that a `.` will be thrown out and allow the default controller to serve it.